# Normalize unicode

Tags: unicode, solr

Let's say I have document indexed with Apache Solr that contains this string:

> Klüft skräms inför

I want to be able to find it with search using this keyword (note the "u"-"ü"):

> kluft

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) for both the index and query analyzers.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is also the [MappingCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#CharFilterFactories), which is used by some popular Solr clients. I'm not sure if it offers any particular advantages over the `ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory`, which is certainly more comprehensive. We find ourselves occasionally having to make updates to our standard `mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt` file at [Websolr](http://websolr.com/) to accommodate clients that use the `MappingCharFilterFactory`.